# extJS: Adding grid.Panel from Controller to View causes application to hang (MVC)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I am trying to dynamically create grid.Panels and add them to my View, since I don't know have many "Views" I need before I load the data. For example, I have a number of people in different groups, once I load the data, I want to create a grid.Panel for each group and put the correct people in it.

The problem is that my application hangs when I do it (probably because the Store is being loaded recursively)

How do I add a grid.Panel to my View with data from a Store without it hanging?

My Controller:

```
Ext.define('NG.controller.Navigation', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [{
        selector: 'group',
        ref: 'groupPanel'}
    ],

    stores: ['Groups'],

    init: function() {
         this.control({
            'navigation': {
                itemdblclick: this.onNavigationSelection
            }
        });
    },
    onNavigationSelection: function(view, record, item, index, eventobj, obj) {

        var groupsstore = this.getGroupsStore();

        var group1 = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: groupsstore,
            title: 'Group 1',
            columns: [
                    {header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
                    {header: 'Mail:',  dataIndex: 'mail'}
            ]
        });

        groupsstore.load();

        this.getGroupPanel().add(group1);
    }
});
```

My View:

```
Ext.define('NG.view.Group', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.group',
    store: 'Groups',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

And my Store (not sure if it is needed):

```
Ext.define('NG.store.Groups', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'NG.model.Person',
    model: 'NG.model.Person'
});
```

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Andreas

Comment: the problem might be because you assign the same store to all grids

Comment: Hi nscrob, thank you for your reply. I am actually using the above code with only one store and that fails, so I haven't tried adding more yet (because that will obviously also fail). Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: Are there any error messages on the console of your browser?

Comment: "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" after a few mins. I am probably referencing something to itself and causing an infinite loop, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After walking through each reference I could not find any errors in the code. However I found a bug report about a similar problem:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141804-4.0.5-Grid-Uncaught-RangeError-Maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded

I downloaded the Framework last week, and there was an update a few days ago, which solved this bug and my problem as well.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The store.load() event is asynchronous.
Try switching the add panel and load store events around:

```
this.getGroupPanel().add(group1);
groupsstore.load();
```

The other thing is it doesn't look like you are passing anything to the store to load it. So you can just autoload it and have the data ready ahead of time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :)

I tried switching the events around and autoloading the store, but with the same result, the application hangs. I also tried creating a local store (just in the navigation controller) and adding that, which also caused the application to hang (which I didn't expect). So as soon as you add a grid.Panel with a "loaded" store, then the application hangs. If I comment out groupsstore.load, then the grid.Panel is added fine.